# Can 'read.table' be used to read a data.frame if there are non-alphanumeric characters in the header?

Tags: r

Non-alphanumeric characters seem to bring trouble when `read.table` is used to read a data.frame with such characters in the header:

```
A <- read.table( text = ' "X" "Y"  "X+Y"      "X<Y" 
                           3   5  " 3+5 = 8"  " 3<5 = TRUE"
                          12   1  "12+1 = 13" "12<1 = FALSE"',
                 header = TRUE )

B <- read.table( text = '  3   5  " 3+5 = 8"  " 3<5 = TRUE"
                          12   1  "12+1 = 13" "12<1 = FALSE"',
                 col.names = c("X","Y","X+Y","X<Y") )

C <- A
names(C) <- c("X","Y","X+Y","X<Y")
```

.

```
> A
   X Y       X.Y        X.Y.1
1  3 5   3+5 = 8   3<5 = TRUE
2 12 1 12+1 = 13 12<1 = FALSE
> B
   X Y       X.Y        X.Y.1
1  3 5   3+5 = 8   3<5 = TRUE
2 12 1 12+1 = 13 12<1 = FALSE
> C
   X Y       X+Y          X<Y
1  3 5   3+5 = 8   3<5 = TRUE
2 12 1 12+1 = 13 12<1 = FALSE
>
```

Is there any good reason for this?

Comment: Use `check.names = FALSE` in `read.table()`

Comment: Ok. But this means that `X+Y` is not a syntactically valid name. Why does `names(C) <- c("X","Y","X+Y","X<Y")` accept this name?

Comment: Right.  It's not syntactically valid.  But there are ways around it.  I think it's because `names<-` assigns to/replaces the `names` attribute, so it overrides the validity.  But I'm not exactly certain about that.  `read.table()` calls `make.names()` when `check.names = TRUE`.  You can play around with that to see what it does.